# Two Way SSL with Jetty and Null Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, ssl, jetty

I have an application running in Jetty. In front of it, I have a load balancer. The requirement is to have SSL decryption done by the load balancer while the web container does only SSL client authentication.

The theory is that the load balancer is very efficient at decrypting the content and can do that and pass it in plain to the web container.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "Null Cipher" in your title. There are [3 possible candidates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-C): `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL`, `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA`. The first one doesn't perform any authentication, none of them offer any encryption. They're certainly useless for your objective. Use normal cipher suites (with both authentication and encryption) between the browser and the load-balancer. Encryption between the load-balancer and the worker nodes is generally optional, and only required if you don't trust the network where they site (this would be a completely different SSL/TLS connection anyway and have nothing to do with the client-certificate authentication done by the end browser).

Only the SSL/TLS server can request (and verify) client-certificate authentication. In this case this will be the load balancer.

If you want to have your SSL/TLS traffic handled by your load balancer, it should verify the certificate (presumably against a CA you have configured), and then relay the certificate information to the worker nodes.

How you do this will depend on the load-balancer. If it's an Apache Httpd server, `mod_proxy_ajp` will relay the client certificate via the AJP protocol (`SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars`). `mod_jk` is also able to relay the full client-certificate chain if needed (`JkOptions +ForwardSSLCertChain`).

If you want to use `mod_proxy_http`, a trick is to pass the certificate via an HTTP header ([`mod_header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header)), using something like `RequestHeader set X-ClientCert %{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s`. You should make sure this header is cleared if it comes from the client's browser (who could forge it otherwise). In this case, you'll need to write a filter as part of your Jetty server to handle that header an place it into the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` `HttpServletRequest` attribute (it should be an array of `X509Certificate`). After this, you should be more or less at the same stage as what you would have with AJP. This may also work with other load balancers if they're capable of populating an HTTP header in a similar way.

Comment: Bruno, Thanks for your answer. I guess you are right the Null Cipher reference is a bit misguided. I was nder the impression that it would be part of the solution. What you describe in the second solutions ressembles more what I an after. What is the common designation for this appraoch? Is it a standard thing? You say "in this case ...". Does "this" refer to  the case where the header is coming from a browser or does it refer to the approach in general? thanks.

Comment: The header should never be coming from the browser, only inserted by the load balancer (if you use a header). In all cases, client-certificate verification will be done by the SSL/TLS server, which is the load balancer (another option would be to handle the SSL/TLS connection in each worker node, using another type of load balancer, but you said in your question that it's not what you want). I don't think there's a standard to say which header you should use (if you use this instead of APJ).